# how can i fetch data from mysql database and display it to view using codeigniter .

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

hey guys i have a table in database and i want to retrieve data from it and display to view . . i have tried many methods but none of these working . . pls help . . this is my controller code:

```
function getname()
{
    $this->load->model('user'); //load the user class
    $data['member'] = $this->user->ar_getwhere();
    $this->load->view('home_content_view', $data);
}
```

this is my model:

```
function ar_getwhere()
{
    $this->db->select('');
    $this->db->from('tbl_members');
    $this->db->where('member_name',$this->input->post('member_name'));
    $q = $this->db->get('');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach($q->result() as $row) 
        {
            $data=$row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are receiving post data in the model? You should receive post data in the controller and send it to the model, and then, catch its response...

Comment: @JoãoDias modify my code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what errors you're experiencing but anyway

You are receiving post data in the model? You should receive post data in the controller and send it to the model, and then, catch its response... And you should send the whole response as well.

```
function getname()
{
    $this->load->model('user'); //load the user class
    $data['member'] = $this->user->ar_getwhere($this->input->post('member_name'));
    $this->load->view('home_content_view', $data);
}


function ar_getwhere($memberName)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_members');
    $this->db->where('member_name',$memberName);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: João Dias  it gives A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: member

Filename: views/home_content_view.php

Line Number: 17

Comment: @Jay It is an error in variable you're passing to the view. Notice that you're now getting an object with the info from the database. IS the posted variable being setted with any value? Echo it and see. Also try, in the view `print_r($member)` to check if it all the data is getting to the view

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = $this->db->select('*')->from('tbl_members')
->where('member_name', $this->input->post('member_name'))
->get();
```